# How to change the "ReplyRecipients" in Outlook web Addin?

Tags: outlook, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins, outlook-restapi

I use the new Outlook beta client on Windows (1.2023.607.100).

I'm trying to convert old OutlookAddin to the new version.

In one of them, I have to change the ReplyRecipients property.

Before i was using this :

```
  currentItem.ReplyRecipients.Add(REPLY_EMAIL);
  currentItem.ReplyRecipients.Add(sendAccount.SmtpAddress);
```

Now in the new version I have the `Office.context.mailbox.item`, but I couldn't find any reference to ReplyRecipients.

How to add a new ReplyRecienpients in Outlook for web Api ?

---

Edit : Has the Outlook Add-ins Team - MSFT say, this is not implement as now, so i create a request for it :

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/add-the-replyrecipients-list-to-the-item-context-like-before-in/idi-p/3849247

Comment: For adding recipients, you can refer to documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.recipients?view=outlook-js-preview.

Comment: I want to change the Reply recipients, not the To recipients. I want that the reply email is a différent one that the From email.

Answer (score 1):

The Office JavaScript API (`OfficeJS`) doesn't provide any property or method for that. You may take a look at the Graph API or EWS whether it provides anything for that, so you could use it from Office web add-ins.

You can post or vote for an existing feature request on [Tech Community](https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions) where they are considered when the Office dev team goes through the planning process.

Comment: I know how to change it in graph when i create a new message from a batch, but hoẇto change the current message ReplyRecipients with the Graph in a addin context?

Comment: This [sample](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sample-office-addin) demonstrates how to use the Microsoft Graph JavaScript SDK to access data in Office 365 from Office Add-ins.

Answer (score 1):

For setting Reply Recipient there are no API available as of now. Thanks for reporting this issue. After careful consideration, our team has decided to not fix this issue in the short term. We recommend you to upvote or create a new [Tech Community](https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions) item, this will give us visibility of the commonality of it and will help with our prioritization. If we end up working on this issue we will re-activate as needed.

Comment: Thx, I have create the request, for now i stay with old Outlook version and my previous Addin